# Telnet Reset with VBscript / Wscript

Tags: vbscript, telnet, wsh

This VBSCRIPT code throws a 800A0400 error.  Any thoughts?

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 500
'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized
'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 123.456.789.01"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'
'USERNAME
WshShell.SendKeys "USERNAMEHERE"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
'PASSWORD
WshShell.SendKeys "PASSWORDHERE"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
'RESET
WshShell.SendKeys "reset"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
'CONFIRM
WshShell.SendKeys "y"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
'Step 3 - Exit Command Window
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Quit 
</script>
</job>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to google for the error code you are getting or for script file XML syntax? You are missing `<package>` root element and probably you have wrong file name extension (should be .wsf).